how to find and replace and add new string from particular position either tuple or list or string using python
I have a string with is required to replace multiple places and add new string from particular position.
Input is
[(stack_overflow('abc','xyz')\n stack_overflow_is_used_for_queries('defgh','mnopq')\n stack_overflow('abc','ijk')\n stack_overflow_is_used_for_queries('defgh','mnopq'))]
output like:
[(search_site('xyz','ijklmn')\n best_search_for_queries('mnopq','search_string')\n search_site('ijk','ijklmn')\n stack best_search_for_queries('mnopq','search_string'))]
Note: which text is bold that would be find and replace, which text is ITALIC that is remove from input and add as a new text in output

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It isn't very clear what it is you're trying to do.  Please explain in detail what it is you're trying to do and also include your code.  What is being searched for and what is being replaced?  More so, what exactly is your question?

Looks like you forgot to post the code you're struggling with. Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

Use python string find() and replace() methods according to your code.

how to add string in particular position, if you see input [(stack_overflow('abc','xyz')) here we need to remove 'abc' and after 'xyz' need to add some text; xyz is not same for the tuples it is dynamic so we need to identify the position of dynamic variable and add the string - is there any solution

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can use str.replace to replace certain substrings with others.
For your example you could do
txt.replace("stack_overflow_is_used_for_queries", "best_search_for_queries")
   .replace("stack_overflow", "search_site")
   ...

and so on for all the strings you want to replace.
You can read more about str.replace on W3 schools

Please do not direct to W3 Schools. The official Python documentation is preferred. In this case here

@SIGHUP Why is it preferred? It is very brief and has no examples so I'm not sure this user would understand.

The official documentation is preferred because it's the SSOT

how to add string in particular position, if you see input [(stack_overflow('abc','xyz')) here we need to remove 'abc' and after 'xyz' need to add some text; xyz is not same for the tuples it is dynamic so we need to identify the position of dynamic variable and add the string - is there any solution
